# ¿Cómo crear un grid data set con Dojo 2?

Tags: tablas, dojo

Estoy creando una tabla con dojo 2, tengo que basarme en un ejemplo que proporcionaré a continuación, pero no entiendo el código.

El ejemplo es el siguiente: [ejemplo dojo2](https://codesandbox.io/s/8zro6m4kj9)

He visto que se puede modificar fácilmente las columnas en `columnConfig`, pero no sé como modificar las filas.

```
    page: number,
    pageSize: number,
    options: FetcherOptions = {}
) => {
    const offset = (page - 1) * pageSize;
    const response = await fetch(
```

Lo que puedo apreciar en el trozo de código anterior, es que se define `page`, `pageSize`, `offset`, pero no se asigna ningún valor, y que `offset` se está calculando en base a variables no definidas.